# Create a "Hall Monitor" Badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Could a "Hall Monitor" Badge or a "Teacher's Assistant" Badge be created for users on SO which answer 10+ questions which are tagged as homework?

Comment: Wouldn't a better name be Teacher's Assistant, or Tutor?

Comment: There is a tag badge for homework.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Badges are supposed to encourage good behavior; why is answering [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) questions better than answering other questions?

Comment: Other badges could be created for specific tags, e.g. a "Java addict" or "data structures architect" badge.

Comment: @David There are already [tag badges](http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that!:)

Answer (score 7):

*Hall Monitor* sounds like a badge you'd give to over-active migrators (sending kids on their way to the right destination instead of hanging out and causing trouble), not to people who answer homework (what hall monitor helps people with their homework?).

If you were going to give a badge for it, and that's a tremendously big *if*, *study aide* or something like that would be more appropriate.

Comment: You really have a chip on your shoulder about questions getting migrated to programmers, don't you?

Comment: @jinguy thanks for assuming good faith, I really appreciate it. A [hall monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_monitor) actually does police school hallways to make sure kids go to the right destination. In the context of the Stack Exchange system, doesn't that sound like something a person who opts to migrate a lot of questions would do?

Comment: Good point.  I'll change my question to reflect that.

Comment: @Mark, you are completely correct.  And my comment was meant to be more of an observation that the errant migration of questions to Programmers was bothering you.

Comment: @jinguy Right, you assumed bad faith. My answer has nothing to do with Programmers.SE migration: if I was going to vent about that, I feel like I'd be more clever than to make a passive-agressive snipe about it or people who participated in that question in an entirely unrelated question.

Comment: @Mark, I indeed did assume bad faith.  I'm sorry.  I guess I just saw a correlation, and assumed causation.

Comment: @jinguy no problem, happens to the best of us.

Comment: @Mark (side note, it's JJnguy)

Comment: @JJnguy oops, sorry. I *do* have a chip on my shoulder about the double-J.

Comment: @Mark, fair enough.  I decided to finally change my name from 'jjn' to 'JJn' because too many people make that mistake.  The font used here must suck.

Comment: +1 because a badge for encouraging people to vote questions to where they belong would be cool (and generally an encouragement of good behavior). Probably should only be awarded to people who vote for the location where the question actually gets moved to, and should probably have a fairly high bar to clear (100 moves?).

Answer (score 6):

There's already a [badge for that](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/396/homework).